# Micro apps with Angular 7 - Zone.js and custom elements issues

Tags: angular, microservices, zone.js

I'm pretty new in developing Angular (7), because I think about the architecture for a new large web project. So I play a little bit with the possible options, especially using a micro frontend.

I created two angular projects -> **"micro-app-shell"** and **"micro-app-a"**.

The shell is the outer container of the web application, which manages several micro-apps.

I read some articals about micro apps with angular and want to try the custom-elements approach.

**"micro-app-a"**

excerpt of **"app.module.ts"**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ClientAComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  // bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  entryComponents: [
    ClientAComponent,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {

  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const appElement = createCustomElement(ClientAComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('client-a', appElement);
  }

}
```

**"app.component.html"**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Client A Micro App
  </h1>
</div>
```

I build the application with following command:

```
ng build --output-hashing none --output-path C:/Dev/mdo_workspace/micro-app-test/micro-app-shell/src/assets/scripts
```

**"micro-app-shell"**

I added following to  of index.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/scripts/runtime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/scripts/polyfills.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/scripts/styles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

I extend the app.module.ts with schemas part

```
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
```

**Now my questions/issues**

1 a) When I uncomment in **"micro-app-a" -> polyfills.js** the zone.js import (import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; ) and run the "micro-app-shell" I get the error

> Zone already loaded.

1 b) When I comment in **"micro-app-a" -> polyfills.js** the zone.js import (import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; ) and run the "micro-app-shell" I get the error

> In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js

Wat is the right way to prevent this errors? Or can I irgnore it?

2) When I apply changes of question 1a and start the **"micro-app-shell"** I want to show the **"micro-app-a"** as custom element in app.comment.html like this:

```
<div>
  <client-a></client-a>
</div>
```

The content of **"micro-app-shell"** - **"app.component.html"** is shown but I get the error:

> Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator,
>   this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

I following samples like this:

https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/05/04/microservice-clients-with-web-components-using-angular-elements-dreams-of-the-near-future.aspx
https://www.ngdevelop.tech/angular-elements/

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example above looks like it should work. I was also getting the same error and it looks like there are some browser support issues. I was able to get everything working by adding `@webcomponents/custom-elements`

```
npm install @webcomponents/custom-elements
```

Then added the following at the end of `polyfills.ts`

```
// Used for browsers with partially native support of Custom Elements
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim';

// Used for browsers without a native support of Custom Elements
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min';
```

Answer (score 0):

You check my sample project here
https://github.com/xmlking/angular-elements-in-angular-shell
I am still planing improve developer experience

Answer (score 0):

This issue has already fixed in the latest version of zone.js 0.8.28, please check it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I updated first the version to 0.8.28 and it didn't work. But I found, that a import in main.ts "import './polyfills';" or "import 'zone.js/dist/zone' was missing. After adding this, the zone error is gone. But the other is still there.

Comment: could you provide a reproduce repo in `angular/zone.js` repo here, https://github.com/angular/zone.js